# How do i use multiple csv files here and make the graph update itself every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Here is my code. I m currently using 2 csv files and  when i add third one nothing appears on the screen. How do i add multiple csv files here? 
Graph should update itself for each csv files in every 5 seconds.
I need your help, what code has to be added to make it even more dynamic.
I tried this part in code to make it work with 3 csv, But it din work.

```
    function updateData() {

    // Get the data again
    d3.csv("data-alt.csv", function(error, data) {
    d3.csv("alt.csv-data", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
        });
```

Here is the overall code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Parse the date / time
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    // Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left").ticks(5);

    // Define the line
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

    // Adds the svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Get the data
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline(data));

        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);

    });

    var inter = setInterval(function() {
        updateData();
    }, 5000);

    // ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
    function updateData() {

        // Get the data again
        d3.csv("data-alt.csv", function(error, data) {
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.date = parseDate(d.date);
                d.close = +d.close;
            });

            // Scale the range of the data again
            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

            // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
            var svg = d3.select("body").transition();

            // Make the changes
            svg.select(".line")   // change the line
                .duration(750)
                .attr("d", valueline(data));
            svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
                .duration(750)
                .call(xAxis);
            svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
                .duration(750)
                .call(yAxis);

        });
    }

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should break your function that handles parsing the result into another function, then just call d3.csv multiple times passing in the correct URL for the csv and the specific handler for that csv file.

Here is a quick snippet with the changes i suggested:

```js
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.close);
  });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

function processDataCsv(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.close;
  })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
}

function processAnotherCsv(error, data) {
  // TODO: implement processing
}

function processYetAnotherCsv(error, data) {
  // TODO: implement processing
}


// ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
function updateData() {
  // Get the data again
  d3.csv("data.csv", processDataCsv);
  d3.csv("another.csv", processAnotherCsv);
  d3.csv("yetAnother.csv", processYetAnotherCsv);
}

// Get the data, just use the function you already wrote to do that
updateData();

var inter = setInterval(function() {
  updateData();
}, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px Arial;
}

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Error:{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 40,
  "colno": 17
}

Comment: @donasG yeah, this won't run in the snippet manager but that's because of the script reference and whatnot, not the code.

Comment: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined' because the path to your CSV file is hard coded to  data.csv which doesn't exist so you cant loop over nothing. This isn't a copy and paste solution for you, this is an example of how the code should look.